# PHP Post Is Not Recieving Vars Correctly

Tags: php

I have this script here:

```php
<?php
//Tell the requester to output response as JSON
//header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

//POST information.
$name = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$mysql_server = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_dbname = 'test';

//Set up variables needed for middle-end
$return_code = 0;
$error_message = '';

//Connect to the Database
$conn = new mysqli($mysql_server, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    //Return an error (in JSON format) that MySQL server wont connect
    $return_code = -1;
    $error_message = 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . $conn->connect_error;
}
else
{
    //Query for a User/Pass match

    $sqlquery = "SELECT ucid FROM test WHERE ucid = '" . $name . "' AND password = '" . hash('sha256', $pass) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
     //On Successful User/Pass
            $return_code = 1;
    }
    elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
            //On Failed User/Pass
            $return_code = 0;
            $error_message = 'Incorrect Username or Password';
    }
    else 
    {
        //Something went wrong
        $return_code = -1;
        $error_message = 'You messed something up real good.';
    }
}

if($return_code == 1)
{
    $jsonResults = array('return_code' => $return_code);
}
elseif ($return_code == (0 || -1))
{
    $jsonResults = array('return_code' => $return_code, 'error_message' => $error_message);
}


$echoJSON = json_encode($jsonResults, 1);
echo $echoJSON;
echo '<br><br>';
echo 'return code = ' . $return_code . ' and message: ' . $error_message;
echo '<br>Query Passed: ' . $sqlquery;
echo 'Username passed was: ' . $name . 'and Password passed was: ' . $pass;

?>
```

Basically put, you pass it a username & password, the script then connects to a MySQL server and does a SQL query of the username + the password after its been sha256 hashed. The point of the query is to see if the username + password is valid combination. If one of them is wrong, the query should show 0 results, thus resulting in an 'Incorrect username or password' message

However, when I run the script and echo the results, apparently nothing is getting passed:

```html
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: jsonResults in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha-test\db.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
null<br><br>return code = 0 and message: Incorrect Username or Password<br>Query Passed: SELECT ucid FROM test WHERE ucid = '' AND password = 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'Username passed was: and Password passed was:
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please paste your code in your post instead of providing pastebin link. In your log, it seems the username variable is empty.

Comment: Ill add that im using Postman to test it: .e.g alpha-test/db.php?username=test&password=test @HichemBOUSSETTA

Comment: I posted the answer. you're sending the parameters in the url, which means you must get them using $_GET. You can use also $_REQUEST to be able to retrieve GET/POST variables using the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be something to do with postman ( I've never used that ).   The best way to test this is to create a form on a new page and actually post the data and make sure that is working.

1) When I can't figure out why something doesn't work, I simplify the problem and reduce the possibility of other errors causing problems.  So change your php script by adding these lines.

```
$name = $_POST['username'];
echo $name; 
exit;
```

You need to make sure $name is getting set.

2) Create a form that posts to this page.

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="post">
username: <input type=text name="username"><br>
password: <input type=text name="password"><br>
<input type=submit value="submit">
</form>
```

Submit the form and make sure you are capturing $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] before you worry about mysql or other issues.

3) Just so you know, I tried this locally and I had no problems posting that form and then having $name be set correctly.   So the problem must be something to do with how you setup postman.

GL

Comment: FOUND MY ISSUE! Sorry for the caps but it was a rogue htaccess in my Apache that was causing the problem! Deleted it and now everything seems to work. Thank u so much tho!

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: jsonResults in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\alpha-test\db.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
```

First thing I notices the above error, To remove this, you should declare **$jsonResults** globally, currently its scope is local to block where you are setting values in this.

Next issue is blank username and password, for this please share your form, from where you are sending these. Possibly you are missing **name** property or some spelling error.

Comment: Ill add that im using Postman to test it: .e.g alpha-test/db.php?username=test&password=test

Comment: You are sending username and password via url( i.e GET method) , so use $_GET in the place of $_POST.

Comment: To send username and password via post using postman, select post in place of get and send these in form data fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $_POST to retrieve GET parameters. This is why you fail to get the username / password.

As you said, your are testing with this request, which means you are passing the parameters in the URL:

> alpha-test/db.php?username=test&password=test

You must replace $_GET with $_POST or $_REQUEST. I've written a simple working code below. I use here $_REQUEST to be able to retrieve GET/POST variables using the same code.

```
<?php

//POST information.
$name = $_REQUEST['username'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['password'];

$sqlquery = "SELECT ucid FROM test WHERE ucid = '" . $name . "'' AND password = '" . hash('sha256', $pass) . "'";

echo $sqlquery;

?>
```